# Can verbs simutaniously use the volitional form and negative form?

Tags: grammar, usage, conjugations, parsing

I came across the following sentence in a book:

> 身体を起こし、手足がこれといった支障もなく動くのを確かめた。

and searched on Jisho.org for 障もなく. It sent me to [https://jisho.org/search/障む](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%9A%9C%E3%82%80), saying that "障もなく is the negative form" of 障む。

However, I know that for that to be correct, it would have to be まなくて, not what is written in the book. Then I remembered that the も could be from the volitional form; and looked through my Genki 2 textbook, but failed to find the conjugation for negative volitional phrases, which means that 障もなく is either not volitional, not negative, or I'm leaping down another dead-end rabbit hole again via wrong analysis of what the text means.

Comment: The Jisho.org result appears speculative, not definitive.

Comment: @BJCUAI Do you have any definitive alternative dictionaries then?

Comment: @ToyuFrey No, neither would there be, as you are using a conjugated form. Not really the point though... "障もなく is the negative form" appears from you as a direct quote, where that seems to be a misrepresentation.

Comment: You don’t need to type a space after a comma in Japanese.  It has the right amount of space built-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a negative volitional. It's ~まい and it's not super common outside some fixed patterns like

> あろ**う**ことかある**まい**ことか
>
> 子供じゃある**まい**し

However, it doesn't apply here anyways as that's not the grammar that's happening here. By the way, Jisho made a parsing mistake: the negative form of 障む is 障まない.

The main issue is that you seem to be parsing the sentence incorrectly. 支障 is a noun. The もない means `without any` and なく is the continuative form of ない (it works here like an adverb pretty much). Maybe you've seen the phrase 何もない before? So then 支障もない means without any 支障.

Comment: 「障害」ではなく「支障」ですね

Comment: I think the answer would be more effective using the noun included in the OP's referenced quote, namely 支障, rather than 障害.

Comment: I should have made the connection before posting the question, as I have heard the phrase 何もない multiple times before; I've just never learned continuative forms. (I have a lot of self-studying to do.)

Comment: @naruto Thanks for pointing that out, that was pretty bad. Sometimes you just see things....